# jQuery Get Selected Item from ListBox not working (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a bootstrap modal which displays a select list of an action result in a partial view, as per the below.

```
<select name="searchListBox" size="15" class="form-control">
@foreach (Company comp in Model)
{
    @if (comp.Deleted)
    {
        <option value="@comp.Id" class="text-danger">@comp.Name</option>
    }
    else
    {
        <option value="@comp.Id">@comp.Name</option>
    }
}
```

This returns the full HTML to the jQuery Form Plugin and sets an element in the modal and displays it, like this.

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            $("#searchSpinner").hide();
            $("#searchButton").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#searchResultsList").html(responseText);
            $("#searchResultsModal").modal("show");
        }
```

This all works perfectly!

The problem I am having is when I click the 'Select' button in the modal footer I am unable to get the selected value. This is the code I am using

```
$("#btnSelect").click(function () {
            alert('you clicked select');
            var listbox = $("#searchListBox");
            alert(listbox);
            alert($("#searchListBox").children("option").length); //WHY IS THIS 0??
            var selected = $("#searchListBox option:selected").val();
            alert(selected);
            $("#searchResultsModal").modal("hide");
        })
```

The listbox exists and returns an object, the problem is that it doesn't think any option elements exist and the children returns a length of 0?

What could be causing this? Sorry if I have not explain this well, if you need any more information let me know.

Comment: You know that to get the currently selected value of a `<select>` you can just write `$("#searchListBox").val()`? No need to select the options directly.

Comment: But anyway the main issue looks like it's because `$("#searchListBox")` is looking for an element with `id=searchListBox` (that's what the `#` in the selector means - it denotes an ID), but your `<select>` only has a `name`, not an `id`.

Comment: @ADyson you are right, but the interesting part is that he mentioned that the `listbox` has a value !

Comment: AHHHH. I feel so stupid. Changing the name to ID resolved it. Weird that is has object and not undefined as there are definitely no other elements with that id.

Comment: "Weird that is has object and not undefined"...when you're using jQuery, invoking the jQuery constructor (e.g. `$("anything")`) will always create a jQuery object. It just won't have any matching elements in its internal collection. So it's never completely undefined. (If you were using native JS e.g. with querySelector or document.getElementById then you could end up with undefined as the result, though.)

Comment: P.S. You aid "Changing the name to ID"...if you're planning to submit this field in a form postback later, you'll need to keep the name as well. Otherwise the value won't get sent to the server.

Comment: @AmirJelo " he mentioned that the listbox has a value" Why is that interesting, in your opinion? It's obvious why that would be, because the jQuery object he created is still an object, it doesn't match any HTML elements, and so cannot have any children either. It's not surprising that the jQuery object exists, because the code creates it. Or did you mean something else? It's not totally clear from your comment, to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding the jQuery constructor, I was not aware of this. I'm just using this as a search results list then taking the selected ID so don't need the name, thank you! :)

Comment: @ADyson I suppose that Ryan confirmed that there is a `length` in `$("#searchListBox")`. but it can't be because jquery can't find any element with `searchListBox` id. I think he hadn't checked the length of `$("#searchListBox")`

Comment: @AmirJelo " I suppose that Ryan confirmed that there is a length in $("#searchListBox")"...no he confirmed (as per the code) that the length of `$("#searchListBox").children("option")` is 0. Which would make sense - if the initial selector does not match anything, then it won't have any children either. But jQuery will still create a collection for the children, it just ends up being an empty one. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/us724jqz/